# How to test dynamic channel selection (DCS) with LANforge?

Tags: wireless, testing

I would like to test the dynamic channel selection (DCS) feature of an access point AP.

How can I test it using Candela Technologies LANforge-WiFIRE WiFi traffic generator?

Would the following steps be appropriate?

1. Place the LANforge next to the AP under test, and setup a virtual AP.
2. Set the AP under test to use Auto for the channel selection.
3. Switch the channel of the virtual AP to whatever channel the tested AP has selected.

The AP under test should switch to another channel with less interference.

Comment: I am tempted to put this on hold as too broad.  To properly answer this question, we would need to know what AP(s) you are testing as different vendors have different criteria for automatic channel selection and most have configurable thresholds for a variety of measurements that get calculated into the decision.  While the procedure you outline is a good general process, this by no means guarantees a channel move on the part of the AP.

Comment: YLearn, It may not guarantee a channel change by the AP. There is DCS for continuous wave (CW) interference and DCS for WLAN interference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order seems ok, but keep in mind there is more to the Radio Resource Managment (RRM) algorithm than just 'neighbors on same channel'. More specifically, if it is determined that other channels in the area are 'busier' or 'noisier' RF-wise, it may be decided to remain on that same channel as your tester.

Assuming a clean RF environment however, I don't see anything wrong with that test.

Comment: Thanks, to add, an AP would not be able to scan other channels because the radio is already being used in one channel. So it does not constantly choose the best channel. Only once it stops the current communications can it scan the other channels.